# Can I do an infinite recursion with an async function without stack overflow

Tags: javascript, html

I have an async function that I want to call that waits on user action and resolves after some processing:

```
async function waitOnUserInput() {}
```

I want to wait on user input do some processing and repeat, so;

I want to implement this recursively like this:

```
async function actionUserStep() {
  await waitOnUserInput();
  actionUserStep();
}
```

Would this lead to a memory leak or a stack overflow of some sort? Or is this a bad way to model this kind of interaction?

Comment: How do you know when to stop? Recursive functions aren't "infinite" - they have to stop or you get a (wait for it) stackoverflow.....Or are you interested in [streams](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-extensive-guide-to-creating-streams-in-rxjs-aaa02baaff9a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there will not be a stack overflow.

This is because the function *returns* once it processes the `await` expression.

The part after `await` is executed from the event loop, without any additional call stack, and when from there it makes the "recursive" call, it returns before making a deeper recursive call (because of the `await`). And so the call stack is empty again until the awaited promise resolves and things repeat as above...

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
async function actionUserStep() {
    while (true) await waitOnUserInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no stack overflow, because async functions are handled using the JS event loop.

However, you will need to call the recursive function with `await` internally.